# Result from database with promise is not returned properly in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, promise

I am trying to get the data from Db "neo4j"

I have created a controller and a model.
Controller calls the model and the model fetches the data from the DB.

Controller is an async function which is awaiting for model function to give the data.

Model is a promise which fetches the data from DB.

Result in Model is correct, But result in controller is undefined. Please help.

```js
    var neo4j = require("neo4j-driver").v1;

    var driver = neo4j.driver(
      "bolt://localhost:7687",
      neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "password")
    );
    var session = driver.session();

    function get4fomDb() {
      try {
        resultPromise = session.run("Match(n) return n");
        resultPromise.then(result => {
          session.close();
          driver.close();
          console.log("MODEL RESULT : ", result);
          return result;
        });
        resultPromise.catch(function(err) {
          console.log("===========ERROR in DB=====================");
          console.log("ERROR : ", err);
          console.log("=========================================");
          return err;
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error : ", err);
        return "ERROR in CATCh";
        // res.send("404 : Page not found ")
      } finally {
      }
    }

    async function controller() {
      let result = await get4fomDb();
      console.log("CONTROLLER RESULT : ", result);
    }

    controller();
```

**OUTPUT :**

```sh
[nodemon] starting `node .\app.js`
CONTROLLER RESULT :  undefined
MODEL RESULT :  { records:
   [ Record {
       keys: [Array],
       length: 1,
       _fields: [Array],
       _fieldLookup: [Object] },
     Record {
       keys: [Array],
       length: 1,
       _fields: [Array],
       _fieldLookup: [Object] } ],
  summary:
   ResultSummary {
     statement: { text: 'Match(n) return n', parameters: {} },
     statementType: 'r',
     counters: StatementStatistics { _stats: [Object] },
     updateStatistics: StatementStatistics { _stats: [Object] },
     plan: false,
     profile: false,
     notifications: [],
     server:
      ServerInfo { address: 'localhost:7687', version: 'Neo4j/3.5.12' },
     resultConsumedAfter: Integer { low: 0, high: 0 },
     resultAvailableAfter: Integer { low: 0, high: 0 } } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Was able to close the Session Successfully in the same file :

Here is the code of the Modal:

```
exports.registerNew = (input) => {


    let query = "CREATE n Return (n)";


    var session = driver.session();
    return session.run(query).then(result => {
        session.close()
        driver.close()
        return result
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't really returning a promise from `get4fomDb` (As the promise is handled there itself with `then/catch`).

If this **`session.run('Match(n) return n');`** is a `promise` simply return it from `get4fomDb` and use `try/catch` and `await` in `contoller()`. Which makes the code more readable as well.

Also mixing patterns of `async/await` or `promise.then().catch()` is not really recommended, stick to one.

```
function get4fomDb() {
  return session.run("Match(n) return n");
}

async function controller() {
  try {
    let result = await get4fomDb();
    console.log("Promise results::", result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error from db promise::", error);
  } finally {
    session.close();
    driver.close();
  }
}

controller();
```

Comment: is it possible to put session.close and driver.close  in get4fromDb function?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for doing it? Yes, its possible. Not by the way of solution I provided. But if we go by your code in the post simply doing a `return resultPromise.then(...)` would keep things as it is and fulfills what you ask. But then again I didn't go that route in the answer to avoid mixing patterns.

Comment: I am new to node.js. 
I do not know if we should close the driver and session after use..........      In the actual code, function get4fomDb and function controller are in different files. So I can not close it in the Controller File

Please suggest of we should close both of them , and if yes, please suggest how I can close it in the file which contains function : get4fomDb

Comment: if we do not close both of them, will it cause any harm like memory leak etc?

Comment: I haven't used neo4j with node so don't know how much help it'll do. But going by the documentation ideally `session` should be closed after every use ie:(every request/response) and `driver` is an application level entity so it should only be closed when application exits and not with every request/response. [Here](https://github.com/adam-cowley/neode-example) is good boilerplate on how to use driver/session and do cleanup, see if that helps. I also recommend to ask a different self contained question on it to get visibility from knowing people and get answers.